# Using define with double constant causes calculation to fail while inline works

Tags: c, avfoundation, c-preprocessor

In the following sample code, why sample_breaks fails to compile?

```
#define ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2 = 1.0/30.0;

void sample_works() {
    double partOfSecondAVFoundationNumber = 2 * 1.0/30.0;
}

void sample_breaks() {
    double partOfSecondAVFoundationNumber = 2 * ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes this:

```
void sample_breaks() {
    double partOfSecondAVFoundationNumber = 2 * = 1.0/30.0;;
}
```

after preprocessing. So you would expect an error.

Change to

```
#define ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2 (1.0/30.0)
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2 = 1.0/30.0;
```

Should be,

```
#define ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2 1.0/30.0
```

Remember, after preprocessing, `ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2` will be replaced by `1.0/30.0`. You are not assigning `ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because your macro is wrong. It should be:

```
#define ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2 1.0/30.0
```

Comment: +1. But you should always get in the habit of wrapping macros with calculations in brackets (even though this one *seems* to be safe). `#define ONE_FRAME_OF_30FPS_2 (1.0/30.0)`